# Do states compete with each other when they emit debt?

Tags: government-debt, debt, bonds, financial-crises

Let's say that, for some reason (a crisis or similar), many first-world countries' states need to emit public debt to be able to pay the services the normally provide (pensions, health etc.).

As I see it, they would be competing with each other to sell these bonds, right? Would this competition make the government bonds' rates to rise?

Comment: "*Would this make the government bonds' rates to rise?*" What exactly do you mean by "*this*"? Sure, if California was the only state on the planet but all the creditors were still there supply and demand dictates it would get lower interest rates.

Comment: I think you should look at other questions on “loanable funds.”  The question is to what extent increased borrowing raises interest rates.